# vuejs - changing return value inside computed

Tags: vue.js

I use simply computed to get correct values from my array to `select` field:

```
computed: {
   specialitySelect() {
   return this.$store.state.physicianListSpeciality
   }
}
```

this works fine, but I need to get proper values depend on `offer.person` value, which could be: `physician`, `nurse` etc...

How can I change return value to be: in  case of nurse:

```
computed: {
   specialitySelect() {
   return this.$store.state.nurseListSpeciality
   }
}
```

If this would be a function I could easily do:

```
methods: {
   specialitySelect(person) {
   return this.$store.state[person]ListSpeciality
   }
}
```

but in `computed` I cannot do it. Is there any other solution that I could use instead?

Comment: Why not track the current kind of person in a prop in your component?

Comment: @gnud because I want to make some changes within `computed` before I will send it as a prop

Comment: Sure - but some part of your app knows the current person. If you somehow share that data with the component that has the computed property, your problem is solved. Where does `offer.person` come from/live? You're omitting some crucial part of your code here

Comment: `offer.person` is from `data() {return {` inside my component. I used `this.$store.state.${offer.person}ListSpeciality` inside props before and this worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to check the value of `offer.person` and depend on that return what you want to return:

```
 computed: {
   specialitySelect() {
    switch(this.offer.person) {
       case 'nurse':
         return this.$store.state.nurseListSpeciality
         break
       case 'physician':
         return this.$store.state.physicianListSpeciality
         break
       default:
         return []
    }
    return this.$store.state.nurseListSpeciality
   }
 }
```

**Note:** Thanks to a comment in this answer a great solution would be:

```
   computed:{
     specialitySelect() {
        return this.$store.state[this.offer.person + 'ListSpeciality']
     }
   }
```

Comment: This might me an opiton, but I would have to code it for every case of `offer.person` possible value - and I don't want to do it

Comment: If the naming is always the way you typed it here, you can do `this.$store.state[this.offer.person + 'ListSpeciality']`. Might be smart to check if this key actually exists in the store, though.

Comment: if the @gnud solution works then great solution @gnud!